# SQL Query Logic suggestion

Tags: sql, oracle

I m out with peculiar scenario, need to get an logic for writing SQl query, tried my level best but still getting struck.

I have list of companies along with corresponding set of directors. Let's assume company 'x' has 5 directors (aa,bb,cc,dd,ee). Need to find out whether any other company in list has the same set of directors (ie) (aa,bb,cc,dd,ee present in company 'z' too). Even if one director gets differed there is no need to consider it.

lets consider simple example

```
company   director
-------------------
a         xx
a         yy
b         zz
b         xx
c         xx
c         yy
```

O/P required (Since a and c has same set of directors)

```
company1  company2  director
---------------------------
a         c         xx
a         c         yy
```

Logic tried so far:
Replicated input table for comparison, performed a simple inner join, it fetches values, real problem exists in grouping company names which is troublesome in every iteration.

Can anyone help on the same. Really thankful

Comment: Your problem is yet another example of relational division (though a bit different from the usual examples). I don't have time to come up with an answer, but there is an article at:  

    https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1960

that at a glance covers the subject really well. Perhaps you can make something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a hack using `listagg`

```
 with x as (
    select 'A' as company, 1 as director from dual union all
    select 'A' as company, 2 as director from dual union all
    select 'B' as company, 1 as director from dual union all
    select 'B' as company, 3 as director from dual union all
    select 'B' as company, 4 as director from dual union all
    select 'C' as company, 1 as director from dual union all
    select 'C' as company, 2 as director from dual union all
    select 'D' as company, 4 as director from dual union all
    select 'E' as company, 4 as director from dual union all
    select 'F' as company, 5 as director from dual union all
    select 'F' as company, 4 as director from dual union all
    select 'G' as company, 4 as director from dual union all
    select 'G' as company, 5 as director from dual
 ) , companies as (
 select     company,
    listagg(director,',') within group (order by director) directors
 from       x
 group by company
 )
 select     directors,
    listagg(company,',') within group (order by company) as companies
 from       companies
 group by directors
 having count(*) > 1
```

and the result is

```
DIRECTORS                      COMPANIES
------------------------------ ------------------------------
1,2                            A,C
4                              D,E
4,5                            F,G
```

**P.S:** if you need to fetch the data for farther manipulation and the string types are not usable you can use `COLLECT` instead of `LISTAGG` but you would have to define a custom `TYPE` with `MAP` and `ORDER` functions to be able to group by the collected list of values.

Answer (score 0):

My SQL is a bit rusty but I'd try something like this:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM
(select company as c0, count(director) as cd0 from data group by company) ALPHA
JOIN
(select count(d.director) as d0, d.company as c1, d.director as d1, e.company as c2, e.director as d2 from data d LEFT JOIN data e ON d.director = e.director
WHERE d.company <> e.company
group by c1, c2) BETA
ON ALPHA.cd0 = BETA.d0 AND ALPHA.c0 = BETA.c1
```

If you `SELECT *` above, you'll see that either column `d1` or `d2` gives you `xx` but not both `xx` and `yy` in the result set. However, it should be straightforward enough to write an outer query that gives you that.

Explanation: I'm computing the join of a company's directors against other company's directors and checking against the count of directors for the company itself. In your example:

Company a has 2 directors, and both match against only company c.
Company b has 2 directors and no matches for both against companies a and c.
Company c has 2 directors and both match against company a.

This makes a and c a perfect match.

I tested against some more dummy data, as well as companies with 3 or 4 directories and it worked on those too.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
WITH dirlist AS (
  SELECT company, LISTAGG(director, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY director) directors
  FROM companies
)
SELECT DISTINCT c1.company, c2.company, c1.directors
FROM dirlist c1, dirlist c2
WHERE c1.directors=c2.directors;
```

Edit: I can see now that I haven't answered your question exactly. This query only detects matches (without eliminating duplicates and selfjoins). Hope it help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A slight update on the answer by GoranM

```
WITH dirlist AS (
  SELECT company, LISTAGG(director, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY director) directors
  FROM companies
)

SELECT c1.company, MAX(c2.company), COUNT(c1.directors) AS DuplicateDirList
FROM dirlist c1, dirlist c2
WHERE c1.directors=c2.directors;
GROUP BY c1.company
HAVING COUNT(c1.directors) >1
```

This will give you a company with diplicate directors and the first duplicate company.